# How to use the API to show the user reputation?

Tags: support, api, reputation, ruby

How do I use the Stack Exchange API to let my users enter their Stack Overflow URL and then extract their reputation and show it in a profile controller in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be interested in these 2 methods:

- Authentication: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication
- /me (user): https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

You can access the user's reputation quite easily from there.